# probleme getting .SD names for plot in data.table

Tags: r, plot, data.table

i'm trying to plot an histogram in my data.table and it show the list of all name instead of the corresponding one, i'm missing something.

```
data.table(iris[,1:4])[,lapply(.SD,function(x){ 
                                   hist(x , 
                                   main= paste("Histogram of" , names(.SD) ))
                                               }
)]
```

i put only one plot but they all have the same title
[image]

Comment: what you want to have printed in your histogram the standard deviation? and what should the title be?

Comment: the first histogram name should be `histogram of sepal.length`, the 2nd `histogram of sepal.width` etc

Answer (score 0):

a version with lapply:

```
dat <- data.table(iris[,1:4])

par(mfrow=c(2,2))
lapply(c(1:ncol(dat)), function(x){ 
 hist(unlist(dat[,..x]), main= paste("Histogram of", c(names(dat[,..x]))))
})
```